# Docusign Postman Collection Missing Variables

Tags: docusignapi

I have followed the instructions at the following link to import the eSignature API into Postman.

https://docusign.github.io/postman-collections/

The problem is that none of the variables are imported.  When I check the variables tab, it is empty.  I have repeated the process a few times and it is always the same.

Does anyone have a list of the variables?  Or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are not imported, you will need to change those variables to your demo or production environments data.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a demo account.  I would love to change the variables to my demo data, but I don't know what they are.  Any guidance on how I can figure this out? I really just need {{hostenv}}.  The rest of it I can figure out.